# ASP.NET MVC customization - Inherit or alter Framework

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, customization, maproute

If you wanted to alter the way that routes were processed can you do that in a MVC project **OR** do you have to alter the MVC Framework?

For example lets say you have the standard code in *RegisterRoutes* of Global.asax.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",                                              // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
    );

}
```

But lets say what you really want to happen is to have your custom class intercept all incoming requests and route them in a special way. Can this be done with via Inheriting from a MVC framework class and then customizing, or do you have to actually alter the framework code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extending, you just need to write custom RouteHandler.

Look at:

[ASP.NET MVC, Manipulating URL Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755579/asp-net-mvc-manipulating-url-structure)

[Developing Custom RouteHandler](https://web.archive.org/web/20200129202215/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/sankarsan/archive/2009/01/18/developing-custom-routehandler.aspx)

Or planety other on the web.

EDIT:

You can do even more by extending RouteBase and adding it to routes.

```
routes.Add("CoolRouter", new CoolRouter());
```

Comment: +1 Then how do you tell your MVC project to use your custom one instead of the standard is this a Web.config thing?

Comment: Here you can find example:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/755579/asp-net-mvc-manipulating-url-structure