# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Handling multiple domains and sharing a single code-base

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, multi-tenant

I've been wondering about the best way to do this for a couple of days and wondered what everyone else thought.

We want to rebuild and upgrade all our companies websites to ASP.NET MVC 3 and use a common template across them all (mostly); we already have one site in MVC 3 which will be the donor site for the others.

At first I was going to just copy/paste the project, replace all the content with content relevant to each site and be done with it but this would make updating the templates/stylesheets/helpers in future more difficult - we only have a handful of websites so it isn't a huge problem though.

**Idea 1**

What I think I would like to do would be to have a single project containing all of the websites, possibly split off by areas to keep them separated and use routing to send the requests to various domains to the right place and to build links pointing to the right domain.

This would fit with how we're planning on linking all the websites together - essentially with a menu common to all websites listing the various companies, these would link to the companies domain containing sub-menus of items related to that specific company.

This is where it becomes tricky, in that I would need to route at domain level - so rather than routing to the company2 controller on the current domain (e.g. `http://www.groupcompany.ex/company2`) I want to route requests company2's own domain - `http://www.company2.ex/{controller}/{action}/{id}`.

**Idea 2**

Alternatively I could create projects for each site in a single solution and have a common project which hosts any helpers, CSS and JavaScript etc.

Any thoughts on which way I should be doing this, and whether my suggestions are completely crazy? (which will likely be the case).

Comment: We have this working for our certain set of constraints here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/490963/can-have-part-of-the-domain-name-as-a-parameter-in-my-routing-rules/499688#499688

Answer (score 7):

This is a common request.  What you are asking about is called Multi-tenancy.  To date, I don't know of any consensus on how to achieve Multi-tenancy in MVC.  There are probably as many solutions as there are questions being asked about it.

I haven't solved this problem to my satisfaction either.  However, there are a number of blog entries covering this.  Examples include:

http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/2010/05/26/multi-tenant-asp-net-mvc-introduction.aspx

http://codeofrob.com/archive/2010/02/01/multi-tenancy-in-asp.net-mvc-why-do-we-want-to.aspx

This is something that I think needs to be built into the framework at some point.  Hopefully, that happens, or at least someone comes up with an elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - multi tenancy comes up a lot when I've been searching for this. From reading your second link it looks like it almost solves our problem, but I'm not sure whether it does fully - it seems be to mostly be focussed on customising a single product for various users, whereas we mostly want an entirely separate site, with different views and controllers for them all (bar common features such as contact forms etc). I see a lot of questions about routing on a sub-domain level but not so much on a complete domain level.. the search goes on.

Comment: @akiller Has your "search" turned up anything good? The first link is kind of old (and focused on MVC1/MVC2 - although I suspect not hard to convert to MVC3). The second link the blog author seems to have abandoned for another framework (leading me to suspect his solution and/or needs doesn't work).

Comment: @REMESQ I gave up in the end and just added a common MVC helper project for utility functions and added shared CSS/image files on our main domain and linked to them from each of our sites layout pages. There's still quite a lot of repetition with the layout files and such but it takes out a large amount of maintaining. Maybe have a look at schmidty's comment under my original question?

Comment: @akiller I am thinking your solution is the best for the problem. Not truly "multi-tenant" or routing to a sub-domain, but possibly the simplest method of handling layouts/css. Areas really seemed to be suited to this task, but I've not had any luck. I have projects with helper functions/extensions so importing the namespace is easy. I've had trouble figuring out how to use common css (a base.css) that I can then use a specific.css for a site and also how to use common layouts. Now my search continues... :)

Comment: How many subdomain this multi-tenant architecture able to support ? Suppose , we have one sub domain , which will access DB which is specific to that sub domain only , but single CODE base. Is this feasible solution , where we have approx 2K of sub domain , which will be served from single code base ? Please guide and Advice.